# How to use _.where method from underscore.js library for more elaborated searchs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var a = {
    "title": "Test 1",
    "likes": {
        "id": 1
    }
}

var b = {
    "title": "Test 2",
    "likes": {
        "id": 2
    }
}


var c = [a, b];

var d = _.where(c, {
    "title": "Test 2",
    "likes": {
        "id": 2
    }
});
//d => outputs an empty array []
```

In this situation i would expect to get the reference to object in memory but d 
but actually it just works on root properties.

```
_.where(c, {title: "Test 2"});
=> outputs [object]
```

where object is the reference for c[1];

**EDIT:**
 found a possible solution using _.filter()

```
_.filter( c, function(item){ 
    if (item.title == "Test 1" && item.likes.id == 1){
        return item;
    } 
})

outputs => [object] with reference for variable a
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) is the right way to do this, [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) is just a `_.filter` shortcut for filtering on simple key/value pairs. You can see this from [the source](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.5.2/underscore.js#L238):

```
// Convenience version of a common use case of `filter`: selecting only objects
// containing specific `key:value` pairs.
_.where = function(obj, attrs, first) {
  if (_.isEmpty(attrs)) return first ? void 0 : [];
  return _[first ? 'find' : 'filter'](obj, function(value) {
    for (var key in attrs) {
      if (attrs[key] !== value[key]) return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
};
```

The docs could be a little more explicit but at least the comment in the source is clear.

Comment: yeah, that's true. I had to dig a little bit to find the solution. Thank you

Comment: Hey I am interested in this question as well, as I received a empty object as a result. Rather than ask it again in a different way and get marked as a duplicate do you mind if I add a answer which would explain my continued bewilderment?

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz If you're confused by something and this answer doesn't work then a new question would make sense to me. Just reference this question and include details as to what you tried.