# Unexpected results from the Underscore.js _.where method

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

From the documentation of [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

`_.where(list, properties);`

Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.

Essentially you give it an object as the `list`, and pass 'key-value pairs' as the `properties`. Those 'key-value pairs/properties' are the markers you use to tell `where` as what to pull out and return.

That being said, I tried the following:

```
var obj = {
    innerObj1 : { 
                  speak: function(){console.log('My name is ' + name);}, 
                  name: "Tiger", 
                  space: 7
                }, 
    innerObj2 : {
                  speak: function(){console.log('My name is ' + name);}, 
                  name: "Tiger2", 
                  space: 1
                }, 
    innerOnj3 : {
                  speak: function(){console.log('My name is ' + name);}, 
                  name: "Tiger3", 
                  space: 3}, 
    innerObj4 : {
                 speak: function(){console.log('My name is ' + name);}, 
                 name: "Tiger4", 
                 space: 3}
};
```

This returns:

```
_.where(obj,{speak:function(){console.log('My name is ' + name);}});
[] //returns a empty array, WHAT?!
```

vs.

```
function speak(){console.log('My name is ' + name);}



var obj = {
    innerObj1 : { 
                  speak: speak, 
                  name: "Tiger", 
                  space: 7
                }, 
    innerObj2 : {
                  speak: speak, 
                  name: "Tiger2", 
                  space: 1
                }, 
    innerOnj3 : {
                  speak: speak, 
                  name: "Tiger3", 
                  space: 3}, 
    innerObj4 : {
                  speak: speak, 
                 name: "Tiger4", 
                 space: 3}
};


_.where(obj,{speak:speak});
```

This will return:

```
[Objectname: "Tiger"space: 7speak: speak()__proto__: Object, Objectname: "Tiger2"space: 1speak: speak()__proto__: Object, Objectname: "Tiger3"space: 3speak: speak()__proto__: Object, Objectname: "Tiger4"space: 3speak: speak()__proto__: Object]
```

That is where my befuddlement lies. Why would the first method just return an empty object, but second method returns what you would expect...

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888621/how-to-use-where-method-from-underscore-js-library-for-more-elaborated-searchs/20889202?noredirect=1#comment58264936_20889202) but it didn't help with my confusion...
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because `console.log(function(){} === function(){})` logs `false` and `var f=function(){}; console.log(f===f)` logs `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually a pretty well expected result.

You see, on your first example, you create a new function for each object, so that:

`innerObj1.speak !== innerObj2.speak`. The function may appear to be the same, but it's a different object. Not only that all `speak` values are different from each other, they're also different from the (also new!) function you pass as a value in the `_.where()` function.

On the 2nd example, you define one function and reference that from each object so now `innerObj1.speak === innerObj2.speak`, since all `speak` properties reference the same function.

Take a look: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0dpveqou/)

Comment: Of course!!! That makes sense! 
For the same reason `obj.innerObj1.speak == obj.innerObj2.speak` will return `false` & `obj2.innerObj1.speak == obj2.innerObj2.speak` will
`true` based on your fiddle! Right?

Comment: Yay! And because an empty array is a 'falsely' value that's what _.method  is trying to tell you when it returns a empty array...

Comment: Thanks Omri, your explanation helped so much!